# How to identify a patch panel - Cat5/e/6

Tags: networking, home-networking

**In brief**: Is it possible to identify what spec a patch panel is if there are no spec markings? If so, how?

**Example**: I was donated a patch panel by a family member who had a spare; however the only marking on it is 'Net 6'<sup>1</sup>. As I am not sure whether this refers to 'Cat 6', or is just a shrewd marketing ploy, is it possible to work out what the spec is by looking at different parts of the panel? The only other markings are partially hidden, but are look to be a serial number and an inspection tag.

Some searches suggest that there may be differences between, say, Cat 5e and 6 in terms of shielding; but I'm not sure how this would actually look.

Could it be tested some other way?

**Images**:

[image: Punchdown aspect]

[image: Jack aspect]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>: Some searching suggests that a 'Net 6' panel is indeed quite possibly Cat 6; but I'm interested in the general case of identification- say if the sticker had fallen off this panel and so didn't have that to go on.</sup>

Comment: "_Some searches suggest that there may be differences between, say, Cat 5e and 6 in terms of shielding_" Actually, all Categories of cables are unshielded (UTP). The categories are registered by ANSI/TIA/EIA, and they are all UTP. The ISO/IEC has cable Classes, and some of the classes have shielding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not Reliably.

The differences between the Category X copper cabling standards is expressed in their electrical characteristics, which for a patch panel, doesn't necessitate any obvious physical differences. Observe this simple comparison chart (note, this isn't an exhaustive list of each standard's requirements):

#### CAT5, CAT5e, and CAT6 UTP (Solid Cable) Specifications Comparison

```
                                Category 5          Category 5e       Category 6

Frequency                       100 MHz             100 MHz           250 MHz
Return Loss (Min. at 100MHz)    16.0 dB             20.1 dB           20.1 dB
Characteristic Impedance        100 ohms ± 15%      100 ohms ± 15%    100 ohms ± 15%
Attenuation (Min. at 100 MHz)   22 dB               22 dB             19.8 dB
Next (Min. at 100MHz)           32.3 dB             35.3 dB           44.3 dB
PS-Next (Min. at 100MHz)        no specification    32.3 dB           42.3 dB
ELFEXT (Min. at 100 MHz)        no specification    23.8 dB           27.8 dB
PS-ELFEXT (Min. at 100 MHz)     no specification    20.8 dB           24.8 dB
Delay Skew (Max. per 100 m)     no specification    45 ns             45 ns
```

*[Source](http://www.xmultiple.com/xwebsite-forum24.htm)*

In order to achieve a particular Category X rating, cables, patch panels, and connectors must be manufactured such that they operate within the applicable specifications.  However, on *physical* inspection of a patch panel, you're unlikely to see anything that indicates one patch panel is rated for 250 MHz while another only 100 MHz (and etc).  These aren't the sort of things that require obvious physical differences.

That said, it's perfectly acceptable to install your patch panel and *see how it performs*.  Anecdotally, a lot of cable sold as "Cat5" actually passes Cat5e certifications, not necessarily because the manufacturer intended it to be so, but simply because it is of high enough quality.  Further, even if your PP doesn't run at 10GbE, Ethernet devices are smart enough to negotiate the fastest supported connection and will thus fall back to a supported speed...usually.

> *Could it be tested some other way?*

Absolutely.  Any network cable certification tester will be able to tell you if the patch panel meets 10GbE requirements.  You could also connect 10GbE equipment and just see if it works, though that's admittedly a less professional/definitive way to "certify" its capabilities.

Comment: Answered a year to the day! As it happened I did install it and see how it performed, and it seems to do the job for 1GbE just fine.